# Form submit pressing enter (in a site and in another one don't)

Tags: php, html, forms, input, submit

I have the following form in index.php:

```
                  <form action="#" method="post" class="from" id="inviadati">

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Cognome*" name="CognomeCliente" id="CognomeCliente" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" required>
                            <label for="CognomeCliente" class="form__label">Cognome*</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Nome*" name="NomeCliente" id="NomeCliente" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+" required>
                            <label for="NomeCliente" class="form__label">Nome*</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Indirizzo" name="IndirizzoCliente" id="IndirizzoCliente">
                            <label for="IndirizzoCliente" class="form__label">Indirizzo</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Comune" name="CittaCliente" id="CittaCliente" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]+">
                            <label for="CittaCliente" class="form__label">Comune</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Telefono*" name="Telefono" id="Telefono" pattern="\d*" required>
                            <label for="Telefono" class="form__label">Telefono*</label>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form__group">
                            <select class="form__input" name="IDProduct" id="IDProduct" required>
                                <option value="">Scegli</option>
                                <option value="3003">2 49,9 €</option>
                                <option value="3004">3 69,9 €</option>
                                <option value="3005">4 89,9 €</option>
                            </select>
                            <label for="IDProduct" class="form__label">Offerta*</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Note per il corriere" name="Note" id="Note">
                            <label for="Note" class="form__label">Note per il corriere</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form__group">
                            <div class="section__contattaci--radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="form__input section__contattaci--radio-1" name="RitiroCorriere" id="RitiroCorriere" checked>
                                <label for="RitiroCorriere" class="form__label">Ritiro in sede con corriere convenzionato (<a target="_blank" href="https://benesserefarm.com/termini-e-condizioni/" class="link">condizioni</a>)</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="section__contattaci--radio">
                                <input type="radio" class="form__input section__contattaci--radio-1" name="RitiroCorriere" id="RitiroSede" >
                                <label for="RitiroSede" class="form__label">Ritiro in sede</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                        
                        <div class="form__group">
                            <input id="inserisci" class="btn section__contattaci--btn" type="submit" value="Invia &rarr;">
                        </div>
                        <input hidden id="subid" name="subid" value="<?php echo $_GET['SUBID'] ?>">
                    </form>
```

And the following script before close of the body tag:

```
    <script>
        $('#inserisci').click(function () {
            
            var data;
            data=$('#inviadati').serialize()
            //data = new FormData();
            $.ajax({
                url: '../dist/inviaordine.php',
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function ( data ) {
                    window.location.replace("../dist/thankyou2.html");
                }
            });

            //e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
```

PROBLEM:
In a domain and host it works perfectly.
In another one (different domain and host) if I fill the input and it's invalid (or correct) and I press enter, it submit the form and go to /dist/thankyou2.html.
I tested with same browser.

I can't find the solution to solve this problem, can you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Try adding the event on the forms submit instead and prevent the default behavior (actually submitting the form). Something like: `$('#inviadati').on('submit', function (e) {e.preventDefault(); ...your code... });`. What happens now is that if the form is submitted any other way than through the button (like pressing enter in an input field), there won't be a click event on the button and your JS code will never be executed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you. Do you mean something like:

`<script> $('#inviadati').on('submit', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); var data; data=$('#inviadati').serialize() {...other code...} </script>` ?

Comment: Yes, like that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry, but now testing it I see it doesn't sent anymore the data with this change

Comment: Do some debugging and check where it fails.